# HTML-Javascript-CSS Programming for mobile browsers- blackberry vs IOS vs Android

Tags: android, ios, html, blackberry, mobile

Could someone summarize the differences in html tags, javascript and CSS when tarngeting these 3 mobile browsers

IOS
Android
Blackberry

Thanks.

Comment: They all use WebKit. Therefore, I don't think there are lots of change

Comment: Well they all use WebKit based browsers so they should mostly be similar. You mean CSS3, and HTML5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to checkout this wonderfully detailed comparison ! :-)

http://www.quirksmode.org/webkit.html

"
**The Great WebKit Comparison Table**

On this page I compare 24 WebKits in order to prove that there is no “WebKit on Mobile” and to figure out which one is the best. My hope is that eventually I’m going to gain some insight in the “family tree” of all WebKits.

This page only contains tests of CSS and JavaScript items that work in some WebKits but not in all. Adding more items, all of which are either supported by all or by none of the WebKits, makes no sense — it’s in the items in the table below that the differences between the tested WebKits lie.

I will probably add some HTML5 items to this list later on, provided they’re supported by at least one WebKit (probably Safari or Chrome).

"